# hibernate commit: shows committed in log, but actually it does not

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, transactions, hibernate-entitymanager

Please have a look at this code. Persist works for a table called Candidate and it does not for another table called VerifyLink, whereas, hibernate shows that it is being persisted in the log file.
Please have a look at the log below, In first case it shows the query, "insert into Candidate", but in second case, it does not show the query. what is wrong ?

```
protected final void doInTransaction(PersistenceActionWithoutResult action) throws EntityAccessorException {
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        int status = 0;
        status = userTransaction.getStatus();
        if (Status.STATUS_ACTIVE != status){
            count.incrementAndGet();
            userTransaction.begin();
        }
        action.execute(em);
        System.out.println(em);
        status = userTransaction.getStatus();
        System.out.println("status : " + status);
        if (Status.STATUS_ACTIVE == status) {
            if (0 == count.decrementAndGet()) {
                userTransaction.commit();
                System.out.println("committed : ");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            userTransaction.rollback();
            System.out.println("rolled back :");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AbstractEntityAccessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        throw new EntityAccessorException(e);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("transaction close :");
        em.close();
    }
}
```

When I commit something for the first time

[#|2011-07-25T12:38:40.020+0530|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=61;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@15e3c52|#]

[#|2011-07-25T12:38:40.021+0530|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=61;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|status : 0|#]

[#|2011-07-25T12:38:40.093+0530|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=61;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|Hibernate: insert into Candidate (comment, creation_date, currentCompany, current_ctc, cv, cv_name, dob, email_id, email_id_verified, expected_ctc, first_name, last_name, location, mobile, notice_period, password, sex, upadte_date, years_of_exp, cand_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)|#]

[#|2011-07-25T12:38:40.164+0530|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=61;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|committed : |#]

[#|2011-07-25T12:38:40.165+0530|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=61;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|transaction close :|#]

[#|2011-07-25T12:38:47.158+0530|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=61;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl@1fd91c4|#]

[#|2011-07-25T12:38:47.159+0530|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=61;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|status : 0|#]

[#|2011-07-25T12:38:47.159+0530|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=61;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|committed : |#]

[#|2011-07-25T12:38:47.159+0530|INFO|glassfish3.0.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl|_ThreadID=61;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|transaction close :|#]

Answer (score 0):

I added em.joinTransaction() after userTransaction.begin() as shown below and this seems to have solved the problem. It works now. I got the hint from

```
if (Status.STATUS_ACTIVE != status){
                count.incrementAndGet();
                userTransaction.begin();
                em.joinTransaction();
            }
```